# How to apply the coefficient of restitution equation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, conservation-laws, collision

Let the equilateral triangular prism moving with the velocity $-v \hat i$ have an elastic collision with the sphere. As there is no transfer of energy and no force to give the prism a vertical velocity, we can say that it would have velocity $ v \hat i$ after collision.

[image: List]

I want to prove the same using the coefficient of restitution equation. How to apply it here? Or is it even valid to apply it here?

Comment: hi Satya. If the collision is elastic, then $e=1$ so by definition v(before)=v(after). What more is needed than this?

Comment: I get that but while applying the equation we take velocity along the line of impact which according to me is $v \cos  30 \circ $ here and velocity perpendicular to line of impact remains unaffected. But going by this we do not get $ v \hat i$

Comment: The velocity along the line of impact is purely in the horizontal direction. What does $v\cos (30)$ represent to you?

Comment: Line of impact is always along the common normal which is inclined at an angle in this case

Comment: Why do you insist that there is a velocity component in the vertical direction? I cannot understand that. The question clearly states that the velocity before the collision is $-v\hat x$ and $v\hat x$ after, so why are you thinking otherwise? There are impulsive forces with such components. Is that what is leading you to these conclusions?

Comment: Yes. I got it now. I was taught a few things wrong. Thanks a lot for helping this far. I really appreciate it

Comment: Excellent and no problem. Good luck with your studies. Cheers.